# Accord FFMPEG on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, accord.net

I'm trying to get a wep app that's utilizing the Accord FFMPEG framework to work. The DLL that is giving me trouble is [Accord.Video.FFMPEG 3.8.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Video.FFMPEG/).

I can get it to work locally by copying the required DLL's into the IIS folder, that the app is running from. If I don't do this I get the following error:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +457
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +110
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +729
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +247
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +157
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +226
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +73
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +321
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +170
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x64.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719
```

Now, when I deploy to my Azure App Service, I don't have the opportunity to copy the DLL's into the folder the server is running from (`D:\Windows\system32`).

Is there another place I should be able to copy the files to, that would give me the same result? So far I've tried copying them into `D:\local`, `D:\local\Temp` and `D:\local\AppData` but that doesn't get me anywhere.

Any input to things I could try would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try wwwroot and wwwroot/bin?

Comment: I also see an `x64` in the DLL name. If it's a 64-bit binary you may want to [change the App Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDwli.png) for your Web App to match that.